# vb.net constructor for a Public Class array in a Public class

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, private

I have created 2 Seperate Public Classes "Sample" and "Analyte" each with there own public properties.
Class Analyte is no problem but I want to Add an Array of Analytes into the Sample Class.

For example: A sample has an Array of Analytes.

I create an Array with the Analyte class and fill it with info from an excel table. I end up with 31 Analytes. (No problems here :-)

`For i = 0 to TotalAnalytes
     Provar.PuPyAnalyt(I) = New Analyte(*,*,*,Properties,*,*,*)
 Next (I)`

I then want to create a new array of Samples. I'm getting into trouble with the Public Class and how to set the Properties and the Constructor.

```
Public Class Sample

Private mName As String 
Private mComponent(Provar.PupyAnalytnr) As Analyte
'und und und

Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return mName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Wert As String)
        mName = Wert
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Component(ByVal Index As Integer) As Analyte
    Get
        Return mComponent(Index)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Wert As Analyte)
        mComponent(Index) = Wert
    End Set
End Property**

Sub New(ByVal aName As String, ByVal aComponent As Analyte)
    'Constructor
    Dim I As Short
    Me.Name = aName

    Me.Component(Provar.PupyAnalytnr) = New Analyte("", "", "", "", 0, 0, 0, 0)
    For I = 0 To Provar.PupyAnalytnr - 1
        Me.Component(I) = New Analyte("", "", "", "", 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Next

End Sub End Class
```

I've tried to get my head around it but I have the feeling I'm over thinking it now and maybe doing too much or even double...?

Later I'm trying to create a Sample Class Array using the constructor. At this stage I have already created the Analyte Class array (Could be used as a template?) which I could feed the constructor to build the Sample Array....?
Just have lost my way and not sure if this can even be done or if there's a better way?

```
For I = 0 To SampleNr
        Provar.PuPySample(I) = New Sample("", Provar.PuPyAnalyt(I))
    Next (I)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: I'd start by using `List(of Analyte)` then clarify what exactly the problem is.  `getting into trouble` isnt very helpful.  If those values are always the same - or even just start that way, it seems that `Analyte` should initialize them itself.

Comment: How are you ensuring that you won't get an index out of range error?

Comment: I'm getting it to compile now.      I can handle the out of range error later when I get it to more or less function properly.     I'm basically want to feed the New sample Call with my already new Analyte array.